# Нужен метод, который принимает строку, а возвращает её перевернутый вариант (не reverse)

Tags: java

Все привет!
Решаю задачу, вроде бы простая, но не могу дожать до конца. Нужно написать метод, который принимает строку, а возвращает ее перевернутый вариант

**Пример входных параметров:**
a = "hello world"

**Ожидается на выходе:**
"world hello"

---

1. Создаю массив строк, добавляю в него элементы (слова из входящей строки), разбитые по пробелу через split.
2. Вот тут их нужно поменять местами, как я пока не понял. Но есть мысли в сторону, что-то типа сортировки пузырьком, только не по величине сравнивать и менять местами, а так, если следующий элемент не пустой, то поменять текущий и следующий местами.
3. Ну а тут счастливо вернуть результатирующий массив.

Подскажите, где я не прав и куда думать, пожалуйста.

Comment: А вам точно 2 слова между собой менять, а не все слова строки в обратном порядке вывести? По мне так нужно просто составить массив из слов, и вывести массив в обратном порядке.

Comment: Слов в массиве может быть сколько угодно. Метод должен возвращать именно строку с уже обратным порядком от входящей строки. Просто вывести массив не получится.

Comment: Первый и третий шаг вы верно определили))) Насчет второго шага - тут вы используете тот же самый алгоритм, что и для метода reverse() строки (посмотрите его реализацию). Отличие будет только в одном - в случае reverse() для строки вы оперируете массивом символов, а вашем случае - массивом строк.

Comment: конкатинация строк - не самая хорошая практика. лучше, к примеру, старый-добрый StringBuilder

Comment: @Дмитрий прав, конечно же. Лучше всего через StringBuilder, а в return уже привести к строке через toString. 
И еще, надо учитывать, что в результате в конце будет пробел всегда, его тоже нужно удалять.

Comment: @Александр Овсиенко ну это уже не проблема, можно вызвать метод trim() (или его аналоги) у стринга, он отлично удаляет пробелы...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно решение:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String orig = "I love study Java";
    String goal = "";
    String[] words = orig.split(" ");

    for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        goal += words[i] + " ";
    }

    System.out.println(goal);
}
```

Ключевой момент решения заключается в том, чтобы правильно прочитать массив отдельных слов. Читать его нужно не с начала до конца, а наоборот -- с конца до начала. Поэтому цикл for организован так: `for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`. В i записываем индекс последнего элемента и листаем назад до пока i не будет равно 0 (индексу первого элемента).

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Я так и делал с самого начала, но не додумался добавить пробел. Все было даже проще, чем я думал)

Comment: Пожалуйста. Удачи в обучении!

Answer (score 1):

```js
let a = "hello world we are cooking with gas";
let ar = a.split(" ");
for (let i = 0; i < ar.length / 2; i++) {
  [ar[i], ar[ar.length - i - 1]] = [ar[ar.length - i - 1], ar[i]];
}
b = ar.join(" ");
console.log(b);
```

Comment: В вопросе вроде речь идет о Java, а не Javascript. Конечно - алгоритм будет один и то же на обоих языках, но отличия в деталях реализации могут сбить столку нового участника.

Comment: Да, алгоритм был все равно полезен, поразбирал и с этой стороны, спасибо!